# Adding a user on .htpasswd

Tags: apache, .htpasswd

I am using `.htpasswd` to password protect certain directory on my server. However, I noticed that everytime I do this `sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/.htpasswd newuser` my current contents of `.htpasswd` will be overwritten. Every directory of my site has their own user on .htpasswd.

How can I not overwrite instead add a new user on my `.htpasswd`?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Exact same thing, just omit the `-c` option. Apache's docs on it [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html).

`htpasswd /etc/apache2/.htpasswd newuser`

Also, `htpasswd` typically isn't run as root. It's typically owned by either the web server, or the owner of the files being served. If you're using root to edit it instead of logging in as one of those users, that's acceptable (I suppose), but you'll want to be careful to make sure you don't accidentally create a file as root (and thus have root own it and no one else be able to edit it).

Comment: Good gracious! Never thought that switch is the answer, pardon my innocence.

Comment: However, it won't let me modify the existing `.htpasswd` it insists the use of `-c` switch.

Comment: @fishcracker What's the error? `htpasswd /path/to/file username` is perfectly valid (syntactically anyway) and even the first example on the Apache docs.

Comment: My bad. I am trying to do `htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/.htpasswd newuser` in my CentOS server! Sorry, didn't notice I'm at the wrong window. Will accept your answer in 5 mins. Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

FWIW, `htpasswd -n username` will output the result directly to stdout, and avoid touching files altogether.

Comment: Then just append the user:hash to a new line in the old file. This option is also valid for other cases, such as generating from one system to another without apache installed, but which can use apache's htpasswd file (such as lighttpd, for example)